# IntelliJ IDEA code reformat options

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, IDEA removes unused import. I want to turn this feature off, leave the unused imports there. Where can I affect this setting?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First check:

> File | Settings | Editor | Formatting | Show "*Reformat Code*" dialog

Then when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> pop-up dialog will appear.

Uncheck *Optimize imports* and check *Do not show this dialog in the future*. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click *Run*. That's it!

Comment: In Intellij 14 this has moved to File > Settings > Editor > General, and then under a "Formatting" section within General.

Comment: In intellij 14.1.1, there is not setting. It is moved to a new key binding shift + Cmd + Alt + L which always shows the dialog

Comment: @RajaniKaruturi this saved my day. I have been looking all over for this setting since I upgraded to 14.1+. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In IDEA 2018, you can hit `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `L` and the reformat file pop-up will appear. Then you can check/uncheck the "Optimize Imports" option.